# When submit button is clicked, how to do something else before submit in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, submit, react-hook-form

Consider following code

```
const [isSync, setIsSync] = useState<boolean>(false);    

const saveCust = (data: Customer) => {
    custService.save(data).then(() => {
        if (isSync === true) {
            custService.sync(data);
        }
    })
};

return (
    <>
        <Form className="mt-2" onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveCust)}>
            <Button type="submit"
                onClick={(e) => {
                    setIsSync(true);
                    //how to call submit after setIsSync?
                }}
             >Sync</Button>

             <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
        </Form>
    </>
```

I'm using `react-hook-form` and I have 2 buttons `Save` and `Sync`. When `Save` is clicked, I want my app to save the `Customer` data and that's it. But when `Sync` is clicked, I want my app to save the `Customer` data and then sync the `Customer` data.

In my `Sync` button, how do I run `setIsSync(true)` before doing `saveCust`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you could use a `useEffect` hook to call `saveCust` whenever `isSync` changes and equals `true`. Then your `Sync` button only needs to call `setIsSync` and `useEffect` will automatically run anytime the value of `isSync` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isSync === true) saveCust();
}, [isSync])
```

I'm not really sure if that's what you're trying to do, though, because you said "When `Save` is clicked, I want my app to save the `Customer` data and that's it," but then your `saveCust` function saves and then syncs...

Is your `Sync` button a toggle that tells the front-end to sync with the back-end every time there's a change to the customer object? If so, you might want to add the customer object to your `useEffect` subscription:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isSync === true) saveCust(customer);
}, [isSync, customer])
```

Keep in mind that it will now fire every time `isSync` or `customer` changes.

Documentation: [Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)